# Windows. Active X objects. Excel Chart

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, charts, activex

I need to find Excel active X object **mschart.ocx** or **mschrt20.ocx**.

Where can they be found?

Am I right, that they can help me to use active x chart: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa141505%28v=office.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to know about the OCX to use this control in Excel, support is built-in.

Simply add a chart to your worksheet.

Charts are also exposed in VBA for programmatic use.

As is often the case, if you record a macro while inserting a chart, you will get some code that will point you in the right direction.

Worksheets have a "ChartObjects" collection that you can work with.

You can programmatically add a chart to a worksheet with something like:

```
Set myChart = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
```

---

UPDATE 2012-05-18: Following up on the comment below. I think that charting is embedded in one of the Excel DLL's.

You can get the chart controls from Microsoft:

- [Microsoft Chart Controls Add-on for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=23903)
- [Microsoft Chart Controls for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14422)

(GRRR! I can only put 2 links in here!! I'll add another comment for the other 2)

Comment: i know, how to do it. I need active x to interact vba-script with matlab. Matlab must display chart, that it get from vba-script

Comment: - [Microsoft Chart Controls for .NET Framework Documentation][1]
 - [Security Update for Microsoft Chart Controls for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1 (KB2500170)][2]


  [1]: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11001
  [2]: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=26987